# Odoo 8.0 XML ID not found

Tags: xml, odoo-8

- I am create one theme with the help of `odoo` official documentation.
- I use the the `Odoo 8.0` documentation and branch.
- But i have face one problem, When i implement below code[image]
- This gives me Error `XML id not found in parent`
- And i am search `o_panel_body` in the whole branch but also not found that word.
  *please help me , what can i do to resolve this things.

Comment: this id is not  in  website.snippest

Comment: ya i know that i mention is question , i am already search but not found then why Odoo 8.0 documentation was mention this things.

Comment: remove this one and try it

Comment: ya its true if i remove this things then working but why Odoo official documentation gives it?